Cordova CLI push notifications not working
I am developing an application on Vue, and converting it into a mobile application using Cordova. There is a problem with push notifications on android (not to mention iOS), I have been suffering with it for a long time.
I tried to connect them more than once using firebase, I do everything according to the documentation - nothing works. I tried to implement push notifications using One Signal and many other plugins, but to no avail. Has anyone encountered the problem of garter push notifications? I will be grateful for any feedback.

check out cordova-plugin-firebasex, although Cordova CLI has nothing to do with notifications
